# Baxter Moveit tutorial example error

Tags: ros, moveit, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo installed. Trying to implement Moveit example for baxter.

I updated the baxter to the new sdk. Version 1.2.

Runnig

> roslaunch baxter_moveit_config baxter_grippers.launch

gives me this error

... logging to /home/colab/.ros/log/3c0648a4-bdfe-11e5-aedd-000af70eb5a9/roslaunch-ros-monster-10040.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

while processing /home/colab/ros/ws_baxter_sdk/src/moveit_robots/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/launch/planning_context.launch:
Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description_semantic]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/xacro.py --inorder /home/colab/ros/ws_baxter_sdk/src/moveit_robots/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/config/baxter.srdf.xacro           left_electric_gripper:=true           right_electric_gripper:=true           left_tip_name:=left_gripper           right_tip_name:=right_gripper] returned with code [2].

Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Cannot understand the error. Please assist.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224410/baxter-moveit-tutorial-example-error/) by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like your Debain ROS installation is in a broken state. I believe roslaunch is telling you that xacro failed to create the SDF file. This is likely due to using an old version of xacro. I recommend updating your install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade ros-indigo-xacro
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to update your entire set of ROS packages. The best way I know of for this (please correct me if I am wrong here):

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That will upgrade all of your out of date packages (ROS and otherwise), and remove any old and conflicting packages.

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2016-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2016-01-19**:
Still no luck. The roslaunch command still gets stuck.